# Base of vector space from a finite set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension. $S=\{v_1,...,v_r\} \subset V$ and $Span(S)=V$. For each $v_i\in S$ there is a linear combination from $S\setminus \{v_i\}$.
How can I show that for each $1\leq i \leq r$, $S\setminus \{v_i\}$ is a base for V? I tried displaying all vectors in S as a linear combination of themeselves with $S\setminus \{v_i\}$ but I got a really big useless experssion. What is the right way to go here?

Comment: What it means is that each vector for S can be represented as a linear combination of the rest of the vectors in S. I need to show the S minus Vi is a base.

Comment: for something to be a basis of a vector space it **has** to be linearly independent.

Comment: The claim you write in your question sin't clear: What does the last part of the first line and the second line mean?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you're saying that each $v_i$ is a linear combination of the elements of $S \setminus \{v_i\}$.  This implies that $S \setminus \{v_i\}$ would still span $V$, but not necessarily that it would be a basis.  For instance, what if $v_1=0$, then $S \setminus \{v_2\}$ could not possibly be a basis for $V$.

Comment: @yinoneliraz So you meant to write that for every $\;1\le i\le n\;$ , $\;v_i\in\text{Span}\{v_1,...,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},...,v_n\}\;$ ?

Comment: The whole idea is that S minus vi IS V's base.

Comment: @yinoneliraz That doesn't follow from what you wrote. The idea, I think, is that for any $\;i\;,\;\;S\setminus\{v_i\}\;$ is a *generating set*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not true. Consider the following example $V = \mathbb{R}^2, S= \{e_1, e_2, e_1 + e_2, e_1 - e_2\}$ where $e_1 = (1, 0), e_2 = (0, 1).$ Then every element of this set can be written as a linear combination of the others. But deleting one of them from the list won't give you a basis. It will be a generating set, but *not* basis.